# Magento 2: Out Of Stock Products are not showing on category Page

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, out-of-stock

In Store => Configuration => Catalog => Inventory

I have set Display Out of Stock Products To **Yes**

But still Out of Stock products are not showing on any category Page. On home page out of stock products are showing - But in category page out of stock products are not showing.

is there any help or solution ?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> **Run the below command**

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento s:up

php bin/magento c:f
```

Comment: i did it, but still not showing.